# Product of a $L^{p}$ function and measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I read somewhere that the product of an $L^{p}$ function for $p \in [1, \infty]$ and a measure is not well-defined. But why?

If we have a function $f$ and measure $\mu$ both defined on $\mathbb{R}$ then usually we can define the product $f \mu$ as a measure $$ (f \mu)(A) := \int_{A}f ~d\mu$$ for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}$.

I don't immediately see the problem with $f$ being $L^{p}$. Is it because $f$ is only defined a.e. with respect to the Lebesgue measure? Then maybe the zero measure sets for $\mu$ and the Lebesgue measure do not necessarily coincide? i.e. a zero Lebesgue measure set where $f$ is not defined may actually be a positive measure set with respect to $\mu$ and therefore the integral over that set wouldn't make sense.

Comment: For $f\in L^1(\mu)$ your formula gives indeed a (signed) finite measure. If $f$ is positive and measurable, the same formula yields a measure. If $\mu$ is not finite, $L^p(\mu)$ need not be included in $L^1(\mu)$ and then the integral $\int_A fd\mu$ might not be defined.

Comment: @Jochen I see. But if we only know $f$ is $L^{p}$ wrt the Lebesgue measure, then do you agree with the justification I gave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. You **cannot** multiply a 'function' in $L^p(\nu)$ with a measure $\mu$ unless $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$.
This is independent of summability issues and just a consequence of the fact that $L^p(\nu)$ is a space of *classes*.

To better understand, denote by $\mathcal L^p(\nu)$ the space of measurable functions and by $L^p(\nu)$ the space of classes of elements in $\mathcal L^p(\nu)$.
For the sake of clarity $\mathcal L^\infty$ is the space of *bounded* (not: $\nu$-essentially bounded) measurable functions.

The functional
$\| f \|_p:=\big(\int |f|^p d\nu\big)^{1/p}$ is a *semi*-norm on $\mathcal L^p(\nu)$.
It defines an equivalence relation on $\mathcal L^p(\nu)$ by declaring that two elements $f,g$ are equivalent if $\|f-g\|_p=0$.
The space $L^p(\nu)$ is the quotient space of $\mathcal L^p$ by this equivalence relation, and the semi-norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ on $\mathcal L^p(\nu)$ descends to a true norm on $L^p(\nu)$ denoted by the same symbol.

Now, let us assume that $\nu$ is a probability measure. In this way $L^\infty(\nu)\subset L^p(\nu)$ for every $p\in [1,\infty]$, and providing a counterexample for $p=\infty$ provides one as well for every $p\in [1,\infty)$.

In order for a multiplication $L^p(\nu)\times \mathcal M\to \mathcal M$ to be well-defined, it must be independent of the representative that you choose for a class in $L^p(\nu)$.
This is certainly not the case if $\mu\not\ll\nu$.

> For example, let $\mu=\delta_0$ and $\nu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. For any class $[f]\in L^\infty(\nu)$ (hence in $L^p(\nu)$ for every $p$), both $f$ and $f+\chi_{\{0\}}$ are representatives of $[f]$, where $\chi_{\{0\}}$ is the characteristic function of the singleton $\{0\}$.
> Thus, $[f] \cdot \mu$ is well-defined only if $$f\cdot \mu= (f+\chi_{\{0\}})\cdot \mu.$$ Clearly this is not the case, since $$f(0)=(f\cdot \mu)\{0\}\neq  f(0)+1=\big((f+\chi_{\{0\}})\cdot\mu\big)\{0\}.$$

Even if $\mu\ll\nu$, then you still have the summability issues specified in the comments to your question.
Thus, also in this case it might still not be possible to multiply $f\in L^p(\nu)$ by $\mu$ and obtain a measure in the standard sense.

Comment: I see, thanks! But what do you mean $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ is the space of bounded not $\nu$ essentially bounded functions? how else can you define this space?

Comment: There are two possibilities (depending on context, the first one is preferred). $\mathcal L^\infty$ can be the space of all uniformly bounded measurable functions. In this case, it does not in fact depend on $\nu$. Alternatively $\mathcal L^\infty(\nu)$ is the space of $\nu$-essentially bounded functions. This space depends on $\nu$ only via the $\sigma$-ideal of $\nu$-negligible sets. As for the question, I used $\mathcal L^\infty$ since I need functions to be uniformly bounded for the arguments to work nicely